# One keyboard / mouse for 2 desktops, how?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10

I have 2 desktops, one monitor that has the ability to switch between HDMI ports from on-screen display, a keyboard, and a mouse.

How can I use the keyboard and the mouse with both desktops seamlessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using multiple ports in the display is a more cumbersome approach than simply buying a cheap two-port [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). Units with four, eight, or more ports exist, but the price ramps up quickly.

Answer (score -1):

You can give [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) a try. Synergy currently supports Windows, Mac, and Linux. Synergy does this by establishing a non-video software KVM.

Comment: I've used Synergy before, it was great for multiple computers with _multiple displays_, but sharing _one keyboard and mouse_. Does it have a multiple computers with _one display_ option I never noticed?

Comment: Not so much, but from what I understood in the original question, he wants to use the same keyboard and mouse with the both computers, and he has them both hooked up to the same display. I don't see any issues using Synergy.